# Проверка числа на одинаковость

Tags: python, числа

Как реализовать проверку числа на одинаковость. Например нужно узнать состоит какое то трёхзначное число из одинаковых чисел или из разных.

Comment: __Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос.__ Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и __укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности__ при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Будем считать, что в образовательных целях:

№1

```
value = input()
print(len(set([i for i in value]))==len(value))
```

№2

```
print(min(*input().split()))
```

Comment: вряд ли ответ на такой вопрос можно оценивать как помощь "в образовательных целях". товарищ обратился не за помощью в проблеме с решением, а за готовым решением

Answer (score 0):

Пожалуйста

```
def src():
    given = 441

    numb=(len(set(str(given))))

    if numb == 1:
        print('Число являеться одинаковым')
        exit()
    else:
        print(numb)
        print(given)


src()
```